# Routing error in edit method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a little Rails CMS and I'm a little stuck with a routing error. To begin with, I have a basic model called `Entry`, which other models are inheriting from. When I try to edit an existing model, it returns me an error

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/admin/posts/entries"
```

In my `routes.rb` in CMS plugin I have the following:

```
Multiflora::Engine.routes.draw do
  root "dashboard#index"

  scope "/:content_class" do
    resources :entries
  end
end
```

and in test app's `routes.rb` I have

```
mount Multiflora::Engine, at: '/admin'
```

In `application_controller.rb` I also tweaked routes a little:

```
def content_entries_path
  entries_path(content_class: content_class.tableize)
end
helper_method :content_entries_path

def content_entry_path(entry)
  entry_path(entry, content_class: content_class.tableize)
end
helper_method :content_entry_path

def new_content_entry_path
  new_entry_path(content_class: content_class.tableize)
end
helper_method :new_content_entry_path

def edit_content_entry_path(entry)
  edit_entry_path(entry, content_class: content_class.tableize)
end
helper_method :edit_content_entry_path
```

And in my `show.html.erb` I have this:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_content_entry_path(@entry) %>
```

When I navigate to `edit_content_entry_path`, it shows me edit page correctly, but when I try to save edited entry, it returns me an error stated above. When I run `rake routes`, it returns me the following:

```
entries GET    /:content_class/entries(.:format)          multiflora/entries#index
       POST   /:content_class/entries(.:format)          multiflora/entries#create
new_entry GET    /:content_class/entries/new(.:format)      multiflora/entries#new
edit_entry GET    /:content_class/entries/:id/edit(.:format) multiflora/entries#edit
entry GET    /:content_class/entries/:id(.:format)      multiflora/entries#show
       PATCH  /:content_class/entries/:id(.:format)      multiflora/entries#update
       PUT    /:content_class/entries/:id(.:format)      multiflora/entries#update
       DELETE /:content_class/entries/:id(.:format)      multiflora/entries#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the error was in my `edit.html.erb` view -- instead of

```
<%= form_for(@entry, as: :entry, url: content_entry_path(@entry)) do |f| %>
```

I had

```
<%= form_for(@entry, as: :entry, url: entries_path do |f| %>
```

When I rewrote it, everything worked!